# Creating a score count Tkinter-Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, count

I am creating a maths game using python and Tkinter and want a score count in the corner but am struggling to do this.

Here is a very simple version of my code (removed the parts not used for the score count):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
score = 0


def change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score):
    score = score + 1
    score_addition_easy_number.config(text=score)
    return score_addition_easy_number
    return score1


class addition():
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def addition_questions_easy_q1(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(root, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(root, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(root, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190, command=lambda: [change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score), self.addition_questions_easy_q2()])
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)


    def addition_questions_easy_q2(self):
        root2 = Tk()
        root2.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(root2, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(root2, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(root2, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190, command=lambda: [change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score), self.addition_questions_easy_q3()])
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)

    def addition_questions_easy_q3(self):
        root3 = Tk()
        root.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(root3, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(root3, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(root3, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190)
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)




obj1 = addition(0)
obj1.addition_questions_easy_q1()

root.mainloop()
```

when you get the question correct the score count increases to 1 on the first page, however, when the second page opens the score count goes back to zero.

I haven't really used classes before so there could be a problem regarding that causing the score count not to work.

Any ideas?
Thanks x

Comment: you could try using a tkinter variable, `IntVar` for instance. you can attach an on-change callback to that which can then update your score widget whenever you change the actual score

Comment: You passed `score` as an argument of a function, it will be treated as local variable inside that function and the change will be lost after the function exits.

Comment: Im not sure what either of you mean, could you please give an example? thanks x

Answer (score 0):

You're using too many duplicates: root1, root2, root3, etc. Use one `root = Tk()` for the entire script. To use `Toplevel()` to open new window. I change `root1` to first, `root2` to second, etc.

You can see score when you clicked button. Also I put `x.title`. so you can see first, second and third.

Code modified:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Main')
score = 0


def change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score):
    score = score + 1
    score_addition_easy_number.config(text=score)
    return score_addition_easy_number
    return score1


class addition():
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def addition_questions_easy_q1(self):
        first = Toplevel()
        first.title('First')
        first.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(first, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(first, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(first, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190, command=lambda: [change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score), self.addition_questions_easy_q2()])
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)


    def addition_questions_easy_q2(self):
        second = Toplevel()
        second.title('Second')
        second.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(second, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(second, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(second, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190, command=lambda: [change_score(score_addition_easy_number, score), self.addition_questions_easy_q3()])
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)

    def addition_questions_easy_q3(self):
        third = Toplevel()
        third.title('Third')
        third.geometry("600x500")

        score_addition_easy_label = Label(third, text="Score count: ")
        score_addition_easy_label.place(x=25, y=100)

        score_addition_easy_number = Label(third, text=self.score)
        score_addition_easy_number.place(x=120, y=100)

        a_e_answer_2 = Button(third, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190)
        a_e_answer_2.place(x=100, y=270)


obj1 = addition(0)
obj1.addition_questions_easy_q1()

root.mainloop()
```

Output main:

[image]

Output after clicking all 3 buttons:

[image]

Is that the way you want this?